# How to implement the retry in spring batch 2.1.8?

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, azure, spring-batch

We are in the process of moving to Azure SQL Server from Oracle DB for our Spring Batch application that runs for few hours with 50 Threads.

I am getting the following error intermittently

Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Executing stored procedure; SQL [{call itemmaintenance(?, ?, ?, ?)}]; SQL Server returned an incomplete response. The connection has been closed.;

We are using spring batch 2.1.8 and I want to implement the spring retry? How do I achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create custom retry logic for Spring Datasource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53948890/how-to-create-custom-retry-logic-for-spring-datasource)

Answer (score 0):

To retry the spring you need to restart the dependencies to pom.xml files

```
<**dependency**>  <**groupId**>org.springframework.retry</**groupId**>  <**artifactId**>spring-retry</**artifactId**>  <**version**>1.2.5.RELEASE</**version**>  </**dependency**>

<**dependency**>  <**groupId**>org.springframework</**groupId**>  <**artifactId**>spring-aspects</**artifactId**>  <**version**>5.2.8.RELEASE</**version**>  </**dependency**
```

below sample you need to add the following to the main class.

```
@EnableRetry
```

Here are the references with related topics

[DataAccessResourceFailureException (Spring Framework 5.3.16 API)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/DataAccessResourceFailureException.html)

[Guide to Spring Retry | Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-retry#:%7E:text=Guide%20to%20Spring%20Retry%201%20Overview.%20Spring%20Retry,...%207%20Testing%20the%20Results%208%20Conclusion.%20)

[Retry (spring.io)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/retry.html)